# How can I use v-model with a functional template component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

*Vue.js* has an [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Passing-Attributes-and-Events-to-Child-Elements-Components) demonstrating how to build a functional component wrapping a button:

```
<template functional>
  <button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    v-bind="data.attrs"
    v-on="listeners"
  >
    <slot/>
  </button>
</template>
```

But how can I build a similar component working with `select` which I can then use `v-model` on its parent?

I have come up with the following, but when I use `v-model` on it like so:

```
<MyComponent :Label="'Status'" :Data="Statuses" v-model="selectedStatus" />
```

The value of `selectedStatus` becomes:

```
[object Event]
```

```
<template functional>
    <select v-bind:value="data.attrs" v-on="listeners">
        <option>-</option>
        <option v-for="item in props.Data" :key="item" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class TaskSelector extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  public Label!: string;

  @Prop({ type: Array, required: true })
  public Data!: string[];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) to work properly, the component must receive a `value` prop and emit an `input` event whose data is a *string* value. But the `<select>`'s native [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event data is an `InputEvent` object, converted to a string (`[object Event]`), which yields the incorrect result with the bound `v-model`.

To fix this, we need to modify the `<select>`'s `input` event data before it reaches the parent. This requires removing `<select v-on="listeners">`, which would've allowed the problematic native `input` event to propagate to the parent. We then use `listeners.input($event.target.selectedOptions[0].value)` to forward the `input` event with the selected option's string value.

*Steps:*

1. Add a `value` prop, and bind the `<select>`'s `:value` to the `value` prop
2. Re-emit the `<select>`'s `input` event with the selected option's value. This should replace `v-on="listeners"`.

Your SFC should look like this:

```
<template functional>
  <select
    1️⃣:value="props.value"
    2️⃣@input="listeners.input && listeners.input($event.target.selectedOptions[0].value)"
  >
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option v-for="item in props.Data" :key="item" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yv5l7k4zo9?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FTaskSelector.vue)

Comment: Building a non-functional component is not a problem. I was hoping to achieve this with a functional one. I know this can be done using JSX. Functional components can emit using `listeners` which is an alias for `data.on` Upvoted regardless.

Comment: @MaYaN Ok. I've reworked the answer for functional components. I was aware of `listeners`, but did not realize it could replace `$emit` in the template.

Comment: Just saw it now. Excellent!

Comment: @tony19 I removed the conditional in your demo and it continued to work fine, is there an edge case that conditional covers?

Comment: @slanden Yes, that covers the case where there is no `input`-event listener, which could happen when the user decides not to use `v-model` on the component (note that `v-model` automatically adds an `input`-event listener). You can test this by: remove the `listeners.input` check in the component's `@input`, remove `v-model` from the component's usage in `App.vue`, change the selected option in the browser panel, and finally observe the error in the browser console.